# React.js Boilerplate with Antd Hot Reload misses the css but hard reload loads

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-boilerplate

I used [React.js Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) (which uses react v16.8.6) to create the basic template of the app and added antd v5.8.4 in my project. I was able to import all the components from Antd and even the styles loaded first time. When I tried to make any changes to JSX, Hot Reload Module also worked but this time it misses all the CSS for the Antd components.

Before Hot Reload
[image: Before Hot Reload]

After Hot Reload
[image: After Hot Reload]

I just changed the Log In to Sign In.

Console also shows that Hot Reload is succeeded and app is up to date but the css is still missing.
[image: Developer Console]

Expected Results were to load the React App with the expected css of the antd components.

Comment: Can you please provide how and where are you importing antd styles?